# some of google drive mp4 files are not playing in jwplayer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, google-drive-api, html5-video, jwplayer

I am working on to play the mp4 videos from google drive but I am facing the problem that some mp4 files are playing well while some mp4 files are not playing at all insteal "file not found" error shows.

This is what I am doing.
link:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnSGB-C8mEGUmY2U1dhcVNiWjQ/view?usp=sharing
```

My code is:

```
jwplayer("player_embed").setup ({
      file:   "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BwnSGB-C8mEGUmY2U1dhcVNiWjQ",
      type:   "mp4",
      primary: "flash",
      image: image_link,
      width:  950,
      height: 370,
      tracks:[{
        file: subtitle_link,
        label: "English",
        kind : "captions",
        default: "true",
      }] 
      });
```

is there any mime type issue or something else I need to do?
is there any other player that can play videos,subtitles,image poster from google drive?

Comment: How are you getting the links? Are you copying them manually from the Google Drive or are you constructing them through code?

Comment: I am getting from "share link" option and then chose public access and then copy the link.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a direct link to the video? If this link only loads a page with a video in it, that will not work in JW Player. I was unable to see your video loading your link directly in your browser, so I would not expect it to work in the player.

Comment: yes, it loads the page and video within it. how to get the direct link of the video?